# リレーション先のデータ取得ができません

Tags: ruby-on-rails

リレーション先のデータの取得ができません。基本的な内容かと思いますが、数時間調べ考えても解決できずお力をお貸しください。
下記テーブルはdocumentsテーブルが「一」に対して、他テーブルが「多」の関係です。そのため、documentsテーブルは中間テーブルとなり多対多のリレーションができています。

コントローラーのindexアクションで、指定のuser_idのデータを持ったComapnyオブジェクトを作りたいのですが、どのようにすればよいでしょうか。

コントローラー

```
  def index

    @company = Company. 　　#ここをどのように記載すべきでしょうか

    end
```

・usersテーブル
id
name

・companiesテーブル
id
name

・itemsテーブル
id
name

・documentsテーブル
id
name
company_id
item_id
user_id

Comment: 何のコントローラ(userなのかcompanyなのか)で、user_idはどうやって取得されるのでしょうか

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> リレーションができています

リレーションが正しくかけているというならサブテーブルでのデータ絞り込み

```
@company = Company.includes(:users).where(users: {id: 指定のuser_id})
```

でいいと思います

Comment: @chicoありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

`user_id`が何らかの形で得られるのであれば普通はそれに紐付く`User`のインスタンスが何らかの形であるはずです。

```
user.companies
```

のように`User`のリレーション経由で検索するようにしてください。

モデルに由来しない裸の`user_id`が現れてほかに使われない、というケースであれば直接`Company`から検索するのが効率的ですが、あまりそういうケースはないと思います。その場合でも、`users`テーブルの`id`を検索条件にするのではなく、`documents`テーブルの`user_id`を検索条件にした方がよいです。